# What values correspond to OpenGL terms (e.x. for GL_TRUE or GL_TEXTURE_2D)?

Tags: opengl

I'm writing a header.  I need to know the values of things like those.  Copying and pasting this information or linking to a source would be sufficient.  *Do not simply answer for GL_TRUE or GL_TEXTURE_2D, I am asking for the values corresponding to every term in existence from OpenGL.*

Comment: it's unclear what you need here

Comment: It isn't unclear.  Everything from GL_FALSE to GL_TRIANGLES has to have corresponding values, I'm looking for those.

Comment: They can't just be text in source code, they have to boil down to something.

Comment: *I'm writing a header. I need to know the values of things like those.* No you don't, that is precisely the point. `#include <gl/gl.h>` and forget about it.

Comment: I expected people like Andon would answer.  It is your kind of attitude that pisses me off, just telling me to walk away and never lay a finger on the subject again.  People told me that about x86 AT&T assembly, about learning how to use OpenGL, about learning how to use C, and I'm sick of it.  You are all wrong.  It is worth my time.

Comment: What attitude? Up until I read your last comment, I had none. You are doing yourself a major disservice by hard-coding any OpenGL tokens into your own header. If your platform has an OpenGL implementation, then it has an OpenGL header that defines all of those values. Use that, and write portable code.

Comment: If you aren't going to answer the question, then why did I even bother asking?  Also, I expected that it was possible I would need to create versions of these things for specific circumstances.

Comment: @Draeton: The purpose of comments is to get the person asking the question to explain better. If you expected some platform dependency, you should have written that into your question. As the question is written, it is impossible to answer - the *"I am asking for the values corresponding to every term in existence from OpenGL"* is the kicker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's still unclear. Why don't you just use the GL symbolic name in your header? For instance:

```
enum PrimitiveType { 
    Triangles = GL_TRIANGLES, 
    TriangleStrip = GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP 
}
```

Anyhow, the OpenGL specification doesn't mandate any specific value for the tokens. It instead refers to the [Implementers' Guide](https://www.khronos.org/registry/implementers_guide.html) and to the official headers released by Khronos, which in turn are generated from the spec/XML files available for instance [here](https://cvs.khronos.org/svn/repos/ogl/trunk/doc/registry/public/api/).

---

The only reason I've found so far to hardcode values (instead of putting the symbolic names) is for allowing the code to compile on platforms which don't expose such values. For instance, suppose I'm writing a piece of code that draws primitives, and I'm defining the enum above. I could then continue defining more primitive types, and then I get to:

```
    Patches = GL_PATCHES
```

The actual usage of such primitive type would still be guarded by a runtime check on the version, but this particular line won't compile on an OpenGL 3 implementation (as `GL_PATCHES` is for currently used for tessellation, i.e. OpenGL 4). That is:

1. you can't compile it on a GL3 machine even if you *run* your application on a GL4 machine;
2. you can't compile it on a GL3 machine even if you don't actually use patches.

For this exact reason I chose sometimes to hardcode the values and not use the symbolic names.

Comment: You answered the question, like actually answered it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'll answer the question.

If you have a Linux box,

```
% grep '^#define GL_.*0x' /usr/include/GL/gl.h
```

will generate all the #define name value pairs in the OpenGL header file (and not the other stuff like function calls)

If you have MacOS X, same command but /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/gl.h